# android wearable - if phone vibrates does watch also

Tags: android, wear-os, android-vibration

Assuming i hold this android permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

and i have a method like this which vibrates the phone:

```
public void onClickStartVibrate(View v)
{

    //Set the pattern for vibration   
    long pattern[]={0,200,100,300,400};

    //Start the vibration
    vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);        
}
```

will the connected watch also vibrate since the phone is now vibrating ? or do i have to issue another command ? My goal is to ensure that when my app vibrates the phone that the android watch also vibrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vibration won't be synchronized. You have to send a message through the [MessageAPI](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to your Android Wear app and make it vibrate with the same code.